# Function with pipe in a tibble not working

Tags: r, function, dplyr, pipeline

I am trying to build my own function to select, filter, and arrange two columns in a tibble, but it doesn't work.

I have tried this

```
tbbl <- tibble(rowid = 1:length(letters),
               letters = letters,
               num_let = stringr::str_c(letters, rowid))

tbbl$rowid[tbbl$rowid > 4]
tbbl$num_let[tbbl$num_let > 2]
```

For some reason, the second subset doesn't work as expected. 
I would like to get results from "j10" till "z26".

The second problem is how to make a function that allows me to select rows that are longer than a specific length, and then arrange them.

I have tried this

```
tbbl %>% 
  select(rowid, num_let) %>% 
  filter(num_let > 2) %>% 
  arrange(as.double(rowid))
```

And then trying to build a function like

```
view_text <- function(x, y, ..){ 
  clean %>% 
  select(rowid, x) %>% 
  filter(x > y) %>% 
  arrange(as.double(rowid))
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `tbbl$num_let > 2` will result in TRUE since `num_let` is a character. What are you expecting to do here?

Comment: I am just guessing, Are you looking for this `tbbl$num_let[nchar(tbbl$num_let) > 2]`

Comment: To write a function "programming" using _dplyr_ you need quasiquotation, see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Sonny, indeed, the ```nchar``` is the function that can make it work.

Comment: Thanks to Sonny and A.Suliman for your help. The ```nchar``` function clarifies my first problem, and I will check the quasiquotation now. (Never heard about it before)